Assemble and link assembly makefile
This is a GNU Makefile I made for a collection of assembly listings. It uses static pattern rules to group together similar rules.
# Makefile that uses static pattern rules to avoid retyping compilation

code64      = true print_dec write
code64crt   = printf
code32      = cat cat_golf yes add225 write32 write32_golf varint sum_digits
codedos     = doscat.com doschar.com


# assemble and link into 64-bit ELF
$(code64): %: %.asm 
    nasm -g -f elf64 $< 
    ld $@.o -o $@

# assemble and link with C runtime into 64-bit ELF
$(code64crt): %: %.asm
    nasm -g -f elf64 $< 
    gcc -no-pie $@.o -o $@ 

# assemble and link into 32-bit ELF
$(code32): %: %.asm
    nasm -g -f elf32 $< 
    ld -m elf_i386 $@.o -o $@

# assemble into 16-bit DOS raw binary
$(codedos): %.com: %.asm
    nasm -g -f bin $< -o $@ 

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *.o
    find . -type f -executable -delete

What I don't like is there is still a lot of repeated code. Code64crt only differs from code64 by using gcc -no-pie instead of ld, code32 differs by using ld -m elf_i386 and nasm -f elf32, and codedos differs by only assembling in bin format. Is it possible to replace the linkers with $(LINKER), which varies? Is it worth having assembler and linker flags be in $(ASFLAGS) and $(LDFLAGS)?

I think that the duplication can be reduced if we use target-specific variables:
AS = nasm
ASFLAGS = -g

$(code64) $(code64crt): ASFLAGS += -f elf64

$(code64crt): LINK.o = $(LINK.c)

and so on.  I'm using the standard names for these variables so that we could copy the built-in rule for %.o: %.s to give us a %.o: %.asm rule (or perhaps we could rename our source files to the usual convention).

rm *.o should probably use the $(RM) built-in variable.
And we ought to have a .DELETE_ON_ERROR: target, so that only successful commands result in artifacts.

Target-specific variables is what I was looking for. I'll try it out
